# How to make itertools.tee() yield copies of iterated elements?

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

I am using [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) for making copies of generators which yield dictionaries and pass the iterated dictionaries to functions that I don't have control about and that may modify the dictionaries. Thus, I would like to pass *copies* of the dictionaries to the functions, but all the tees yield just references to the same instance.

This is illustrated by the following simple example:

```
import itertools

original_list = [{'a':0,'b':1}, {'a':1,'b':2}]
tee1, tee2 = itertools.tee(original_list, 2)

for d1, d2 in zip(tee1, tee2):
    d1['a'] += 1
    print(d1)
    d2['a'] -= 1
    print(d2)
```

The output is:

```
{'b': 1, 'a': 1}
{'b': 1, 'a': 0}
{'b': 2, 'a': 2}
{'b': 2, 'a': 1}
```

While I would like to have:

```
{'b': 1, 'a': 1}
{'b': 1, 'a': -1}
{'b': 2, 'a': 2}
{'b': 2, 'a': 0}
```

Of course, in this example there would be many ways to work around this easily, but due to my specific use case, I need a version of `itertools.tee` that stores copies of all iterated objects in the queues of the tees instead of references to the original.

Is there a straightforward way to do this in Python or would I have to re-implement `itertools.tee` in a non-native and, hence, inefficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to rework `tee`. Just wrap each generator produced by `tee` in a `map(dict, ...)` generator:

```
try:
    # use iterative map from Python 3 if this is Python 2
    from future_builtins import map
except ImportError:
    pass

tee1, tee2 = itertools.tee(original_list, 2)
tee1, tee2 = map(dict, tee1), map(dict, tee2)
```

This automatically produces a shallow copy of each dictionary as you iterate.

Demo (using Python 3.6):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> original_list = [{'a':0,'b':1}, {'a':1,'b':2}]
>>> tee1, tee2 = itertools.tee(original_list, 2)
>>> tee1, tee2 = map(dict, tee1), map(dict, tee2)
>>> for d1, d2 in zip(tee1, tee2):
...     d1['a'] += 1
...     print(d1)
...     d2['a'] -= 1
...     print(d2)
...
{'a': 1, 'b': 1}
{'a': -1, 'b': 1}
{'a': 2, 'b': 2}
{'a': 0, 'b': 2}
```